# Reading Multiple files in a Byte Array

Tags: c#, file, arrays

I have an object that has a byte array property 'ZipFile' to store a file stream:

**Property in Result class:**

```
public class Result
{
  public byte[] ZipFile;
}
```

In my application, I generate a PDF file, and read the file into the 'ZipFile' property using my ReadFile method like this :

```
objResult.ZipFile = ReadFile(FilePath);
```

**Signature of ReadFile method:**

```
private byte[] ReadFile(string strFileName)
```

**The Problem:**

My ReadFile method will now be called in a loop, because I am generating multiple PDF files. Each time the ReadFile method will read a new file from the specifed parameter to the 'objResult.ZipFile' property, consequently replacing the old value in 'ZipFile' property. Now, I want my 'ZipFile' property to store multiple PDF files stream. So what should I do for that? Should I just change this property to a two dimensional  byte[][]  array, or is there any better way to do this? Remember, that this property will be used for saving(writing) these files by calling method. Open to all Suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you should *either* have a `List<Result>`, or result should have a collection such as `List<byte[]>` as a `ZipFiles` property. Note that currently you don't have a property at all - you have a public field, which is generally a bad idea.

(You probably wouldn't *expose* it as a `List<byte[]>` - that would be the underlying implementation. I'd probably make it an `IEnumerable<byte[]>` and expose an `AddZipFile` method.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be returning a Result object to the calling method, to Read the stream from its property. So, Why should I expose an AddZipFile method?

Comment: @ebad86: Well *something* has to add the byte array to the list - but it's generally a bad idea to expose whole lists as properties.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am committing this mistake a lot. Although, I am desparate to learn why is it a bad idea. Is this topic mentioned in any of your articles or book? Can you please guide where I can learn more about this?

Comment: Yes, there are some guidelines around this in appendix B of C# in Depth, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `List<byte[]>` (list of byte array) and then append the array in the list in each iteration. Something like.

```
public class Result
{
   public List<byte[]> ZipFilesList { get; set; };
}
```

Later you can do:

```
ResultObj.ZipFilesList.Add(ReadFile(FilePath));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will do this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have list of `List<byte[]>`

```
public class Result
{
   public List<byte[]> ZipFiles;
}
```

And add the files into your list

```
objResult.ZipFiles.Add(ReadFile(FilePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store them for later processing a list or queue will do it. I think I would opt for a queue as your usage pattern seems to match that.

```
 // make queue
 var filesQueue = new Queue<byte[]>();

 // add file
 filesQueue.Enqueue(newFile);

 // get file
 var fileToSave=filesQueue.Dequeue();
```

You can switch to a concurrentQueue later if you would ever need to parallelize etc..